# How to use static library like "libstk.a" in Xcode?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, static-libraries

I'm trying to use [The Synthesis ToolKit in C++ (STK)](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/index.html) library in my Xcode. I compiled its source on my Mac using the "--with-core" configuration option. I added the "libstk.a" into Xcode under framework.

I thought I can do the following in my source to use the stk library:

```
#include "Stk.h"
```

However, Xcode errors with "File not found", which it kind of make sense, because that file is not in my project. How do I use it? I know I'm missing something very basic here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just provide the path to the source, something like `#include "~/work/mySources/STK/stk.h"`. If you use just `#include "Stk.h"`, the header must be in the current working directory.

Comment: have you included all headers related to .a file in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure the header search path of the Xcode project.  Make it relative to the current project, rather than absolute; for example:

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/../libstk/include
```

Comment: Great it worked! However, it is giving a warning:
ld: warning: ignoring file /stk-4.4.3/src/libstk.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Apparently it has a reference to the location where the static library was originally compiled. How do I get rid of this warning?

Comment: @docchang You need to create an Xcode workspace and add both projects to it and the correct version of the library will be built when it's needed.

Comment: I tried it, but seems a bit too complicated. I guess I will just live with the warning for now. Thanks.